# degree of a continuous map

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $f(z)$ be a polynomial with complex coefficients. $f$ can be extended to a continuous map $\tilde f: S^2 \rightarrow S^2$ ($\mathbb C \cup \{ \infty \} \cong S^2$). Prove that the [degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping) of $\tilde f$ as a continuous map is just the degree of $f$ as a polynomial. Let $x$ be a root of $f$, then the local degree of $\tilde f$ at $x$ is the multiplicity of $x$ as a root of $f$.

I think I only has to prove the last sentence. But I don't have a deep understanding of all these concepts. So I don't have an idea for the proof. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is a great question. However, we don't know your background and what tools you have at hand. What results have you seen in complex analysis, for example? What is your definition of local degree of a continuous (or smooth) map?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356354/local-degree-computation-hatcher-exercise-2-2-8

Comment: @TedShifrin: This is the definition of local degree >local degree: Suppose $f: S^n \rightarrow S^n$, $n>0$, has the property that for some point $y \in S^n$, the preimage $f^{-1}(y)$ consists of only finitely many points, say $x_1, \cdots, x_m$. Let $U_1, \cdots, U_m$ be disjoint neighborhoods of these points,mapped by $f$ into a neighborhood $V$ of $y$. Then $H_n(U_i,U_i-x_i)$ and $H_n(V,V-y)$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. $f^*: H_n(U_i,U_i-x_i) \rightarrow H_n(V,V-y)$ is a multiplication by an integer, say $d_i$. The local degree of $f$ at $x_i$ defined to be $d_i$.

Comment: OK, so you need to show that for $g(z)=(z-z_0)^k$ the local degree is $k$, and then you need to show that the local degree at $z_0$ of $g(z)h(z)$ is the same if $h$ is a polynomial with $h(z_0)\ne 0$.